# Linking a fortran static library in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to link a Fortran static library (.LIB file) created with the Intel Fortran Compiler on Windows from Delphi (10.2). How do I do this?

I've tried finding examples online without success. I know there could be options to convert the static lib into a DLL but I specifically want to include it as static, not as a dynamic library. Thanks!

Comment: Delphi doesn't support linking to static libraries created by other compilers. However, it does support linking to individual object files, via the [`{$L}{$LINK}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Link_object_file_(Delphi)) directive.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I will look into it.

Comment: Linking individual object files can be rather tricky. Put the lib file in a DLL and link to that.